# No custom widgets in Qt Designer for QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, qt-designer, pyqt5

There are no custom widgets in my "Qt Designer with QGIS 3.0.3 custom widgets". Is it a bug or I should somehow manually enable them?

Comment: "Before we can use custom widgets in Qt Designer, we must make Qt Designer aware of them. There are two techniques for doing this: the "promotion" approach and the plugin approach." - quote from http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1405227&seqNum=3

Comment: is so strange because I have this version with custom widgets!can you reinstall?I just installed this version and it works https://download.osgeo.org/qgis/win64/QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.0.3-1-Setup-x86.exe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The environment and path needs to be set for Qt Designer to access the QGIS Custom widgets.  These can be set by running the "qgis-designer.bat" file that comes with a QGIS installation.  For a network installation, this file is located in:
...\OSGEO4W64\bin\qgis-designer.bat

The contents of this batch file are:

`@echo off
call "%~dp0\o4w_env.bat"
call qt5_env.bat
call py3_env.bat
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT:\=/%/apps/qgis
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qt5\plugins
start "Qt Designer with QGIS custom widgets" /B designer.exe %*`

Answer (score 5):

In **QGIS 3.2.0**, custom widgets seem to be available:

[image: Custom widgets]

---

*Tested on Windows 7 64-bit.*

---

**Edit:**

- I used the **QGIS Standalone Installer Version 3.2 (64 bit)** and following the simple on-screen instructions. Once installed, I simply ran `Qt Designer with QGIS 3.2.0 custom widgets.exe` which was found in the *Start* menu.
- I also tested **QGIS Standalone Installer Version 3.2 (32 bit)** on a 32-bit computer and the custom widgets were also available.

Comment: For your test: 1. Did you use the "OSGeo4W Network Installer" or the "QGIS Standalone Installer"?; Do you need to set your environmental settings using a batch file or manual process so that QT Designer can find and use the relevant files?

Comment: Also your Windows is 64 bit, but did you use a 32 bit or a 64 bit QGIS installation?

Comment: @PhilipWhitten - Edited post. Only used the Standalone installers for both 32-bit and 64-bit.

Comment: I found my problem.  With the QGIS installation there is a file called "qgis-designer.bat", you need to run this file which sets the environment settings for "Qt Designer.exe" and then opens "Qt Designer".  If you open "Qt Designer.exe" directly then you don't get the correct environment and you will not see the QGIS Custom Widgets.  The "qgis-designer" batch file is opened by the shortcut called "Qt Designer with QGIS 3.2.2 custom widgets" which comes with the QGIS installation.  The short answer is don't open "Qt Designer" directly.

Comment: @PhilipWhitten - Nice detective work :)