# QtDesigner is not starting for qgis bat file

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qt-designer, pyqt5

The qt-designer.bat file did not launch the QtDesigner. I have tried the file available with OSGeo4W64 installation but the qt-designer did not starts.I also try to start the qtdesigner from the QtDesginer with QGIS 3.10 custom widgets but also did not start.
I have tried this solution in this link: [No custom widgets in Qt Designer for QGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285479/no-custom-widgets-in-qt-designer-for-qgis-3/296013)

Note Qgis is v3.4

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall qgis and reinstall qgis? You can directy download QtCreator (similar to QtDesigner) on their website : https://www.qt.io/download

Comment: @Vincent Bré I uninstalled Qgis and also downloaded the qtdesigner, but qgis features are not available with qtdesigner

Comment: Did you try to reinstall from several sources?

Comment: @VincentBré can you please send me some sources

Comment: On the website https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html, you can try to install with OSGeo4W Network Installer or without.

Comment: fyi, you may also download QtDesigner via the fman build system site, https://build-system.fman.io/qt-designer-download