# QGIS Widget on Qt Designer Mac

Tags: qgis, qt-designer

I **would like** to use a QGIS custom widget in a UI window on Qt Designer for Mac. I only have the Qt widgets and cannot find a way to see the QGIS widgets.

I **have** Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6, Qt Creator 4.11 (based on Qt 5.14.1), Qt Designer 5.9.6, QGIS 3.10 and of course python 3, Qt, PyQt.

I **already saw** the answers on [No custom widgets in Qt Designer for QGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285479/no-custom-widgets-in-qt-designer-for-qgis-3) but:

- Most answers apply to MS-Windows. Thus I have no .exe or .bat with the designer. I cannot find a similar designer executable in the QGIS Mac package.
- The *promote* of http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1405227&seqNum=3 works of course, but I don't benefit from the custom properties of the widget. It is not very convenient to define them in the code.
- The *plugin approach* of http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1405227&seqNum=3 is ways too complicated ... and I expect that QGIS did it already, seeing the designer for MS-Windows.
- I try to add some path in Qt Designer preferences (*template paths*) to */Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtDesigner.framework/* and several paths within. Similar in the Qt Creator preferences (*Designer* > *model paths*).

What am I missing? How to get it?

Comment: Did this ever get a solution?  I am running into the same issue when trying to use QgsMapLayerCombobox.

Comment: not that I know... I make without :-(

Answer (score 4):

Go to Application and "show package content" of QGIS package. You can open the shipped designer executable in /Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/ and double click "designer" (running this from the command line might not work). You should have all the widgets in the widget box