# How to use all QGIS 3 custom widgets in Qt Designer?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qt-designer, pyqt5, qgis-custom-widgets

For example, QGIS 3.4 has various custom widgets such as [QgsFieldValuesLineEdit](https://qgis.org/api/3.4/classQgsFieldValuesLineEdit.html) and [QgsColorWheel](https://qgis.org/api/3.4/classQgsColorWheel.html) (and later versions have even more widgets) but they are not listed in the QGIS custom widgets list of the Qt Designer even when I run the "Qt Designer with QGIS 3.4 custom widgets". However, those widgets shown in the [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/296132/52577) by @Joseph for the question by @Basile, [No custom widgets in Qt Designer for QGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/285479/52577), are available:

[image]

Is it somehow possible to add QGIS custom widgets that are, at least by default, missing from the custom widgets list of the Qt Designer to the list? If not, can they somehow, still be used in the Qt Designer (maybe through [Qt Designer promoting widgets functionality](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-custom-widgets.html#promoting-widgets) for custom widgets)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The available QGIS Custom Widgets in Qt Designer are defined in QGIS `libqgis_customwidgets`.

It is easy to find out the library in use.

Go to Qt Designer → Help → About Plugins. You will see the QGIS library in use.

[image: libqgis_customwidgets library in use]

If you see different widgets in your Qt Designer, maybe you are using a different `libqgis_customwidgets` library. You could be using some dangling library from a previous installation.