# QgsMessageBar in Qt Creator

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt5, qgis-custom-widgets

By default *Qt Creator* does show the list of *QGIS Custom Widgets* - but not the [QgsMessageBar](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.28/gui/QgsMessageBar.html). I can make it work inserting it directly in the *Code View* using something like  but really would like to use it directly from the *Design View*.

I checked out [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/388971/60146) for *Qt Designer*, but these seems to be different in *Qt Creator*.

Why doesn't *QgsMessageBar* show up in the *QGIS Custom Widgets*? And how can I make it appear there?